# PowerShell: Grep through object string representation

Tags: powershell

How can I query the textual output of an cmdlet, if I don't know the exact member/ property I am interested in?

For example, when I use the cmdlet `Get-ComputerInfo`, a 184 lines table of the format `Property: Value` is printed, an excerpt being:

```
...
CsNumberOfLogicalProcessors      : 20
CsNumberOfProcessors             : 1
CsProcessors                     : {Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10850K CPU @ 3.60GHz}
CsOEMStringArray                 : {To Be Filled By O.E.M.}
CsPartOfDomain                   : False
CsPauseAfterReset                : -1
CsPCSystemType                   : Desktop
...
```

How can I query this textual representation, i.e. search through all property names and their respective values in a convenient way? Basically, if I am searching for the specific type of my intel processor, I want the output of

```
Get-ComputerInfo > temp.txt
Select-String -Path temp.txt -Pattern intel
```

but without the workaround of writing everything to a file.

I understand that `Get-ComputerInfo | Select-String -Pattern intel` doesn't work, because the return type of `Get-ComputerInfo` is an object. Neither does `Get-ComputerInfo | Write-Output | Select-String intel`.

Comment: See the answer from JohnLBevan, usage would be `Get-ComputerInfo | Find-ValueMatchingCondition -PropertyTypesToSearch Properties -Condition { $_ -match 'Intel' }`

Comment: To search through the _for-display string representation_, as a quick-and-dirty approach, use `Get-ComputerInfo | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern intel`, as also shown in the linked duplicate. Arguably, `Select-String` should _implicitly_ work this way, without needing `Out-String -Stream` (wrapped in function `oss` in recent PowerShell versions) - see [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146).